# MySQL trigger if condition exists

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to write an update trigger that will only update a password when a new password is set in the update statement but I'm having a terrible time trying to nail down the syntax.  This should be a no-brainer but I'm just not finding the solution.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_user BEFORE UPDATE ON `user`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NEW.password <> '') THEN
        SET NEW.password = PASSWORD(NEW.password);
  END IF;
END;
```

I've tried:

```
IF (NEW.password <> NULL) THEN

IF (NEW.password) THEN

IF NEW.password <> NULL THEN

IF (NEW.password > 0) THEN

IF (NEW.password != NULL) THEN
```

And I'm sure many other combinations but it's just not working.  Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think you mean to update it back to the `OLD` password, when the NEW one is not supplied.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS upd_user;

DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER upd_user BEFORE UPDATE ON `user`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF (NEW.password IS NULL OR NEW.password = '') THEN
            SET NEW.password = OLD.password;
      ELSE
            SET NEW.password = Password(NEW.Password);
      END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

However, this means a user can never blank out a password.

---

If the password field (already encrypted) is being sent back in the update to mySQL, then it will not be null or blank, and MySQL will attempt to redo the Password() function on it. To detect this, use this code instead

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER upd_user BEFORE UPDATE ON `user`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF (NEW.password IS NULL OR NEW.password = '' OR NEW.password = OLD.password) THEN
            SET NEW.password = OLD.password;
      ELSE
            SET NEW.password = Password(NEW.Password);
      END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I think he means to implement the password encryption in this trigger.

Comment: @yper - I left that out but the part I was attacking was the fact that to preserve the old, you actually have to set it *back* within the trigger

Comment: He is probably not correctly using `delimiter`, like in his previous question :)

Comment: You are right though, your approach makes more sense. His code would encrypt all passwords unless they are blank, and allow blanks (unencrypted).

Comment: @yper - that didn't occur to me. Without the `delimiter` being set, the code would complain on the first occurence of ';' (the SET line) no matter how it is written!

Comment: I didn't include the delimiter part in the code sample because it wasn't really the issue.  I'd learned that lesson before.  Even with your help, and thank you BTW, I can't get it to not to change the password when an update w/o a password is executed.  I might need drop this whole idea and just add the password() to my application layer.

Comment: @gurun - It doesn't work for you? I tested it fully and it works as expected

Comment: I can't really figure out why but the password was re-encrypted each time a update was executed regardless if a value was present or not.  I've reworked my User object to account for the encryption.  Thanks for the help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @gurun8 - is your code sending back the old password UNCHANGED (but nevertheless sending it anyway)? That would cause it to 'have a value' and it will get re-password()-ed

Comment: I was actually just trying the update statement manually without the password clause.  I'll give your new if condition a try and see if it changes anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do...

```
 DELIMITER $$
        CREATE TRIGGER aumentarsalario 
        BEFORE INSERT 
        ON empregados
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
          if (NEW.SALARIO < 900) THEN 
             set NEW.SALARIO = NEW.SALARIO + (NEW.SALARIO * 0.1);
          END IF;
        END $$
  DELIMITER ;
```