# How to add an automatic "Stale" column in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table that has a "stale" boolean column.  It starts out as always true.  Then, there is a single action a user can take (push the data in the row into a cache) that should set the stale value to false.

However, whenever the row is updated, the stale value should automatically be set to true again.  I've tried making this work out with a trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `update_tbl_stale`

CREATE TRIGGER `update_tbl_stale` BEFORE UPDATE ON `tbl`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.stale = 1;
END
```

The problem here is that I can't set stale to 0 because it will automatically get set back to 1.  Is there some sort of `if` statement I can put into that trigger to only make it do anything if the update statement doesn't explicitly set `stale` to 0?  Or is this something I have to deal with in code?

Comment: why dont you use `ENUM` datatype and set default as watever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you need to look for the case when the trigger is explicitly being set to 0 after previously being 1 and in this case allow it to be zero:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_tbl_stale` BEFORE UPDATE ON `tbl`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.stale = IF(NEW.Stale=0 AND OLD.Stale=1,0,1);
END
```

Answer (score 0):

as for the WHEN clause of a SQL trigger, applied to mysql, see this SO question: [MySQL trigger if condition exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372872/mysql-trigger-if-condition-exists)