# updating a table field where criteria is from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I wish to update all records in a field based on criteria present in another table field.

```
Table name: emp_leaves
Field name: leave_limit
common field: emp_id

Table name: emp_summary
Field name: emp_status
common field: emp_id
```

I wish to run a query in the beginning of every month so that the leave_limit values in the emp_leaves table would increment by 1.5 if the value of emp_status of the emp_summary table is "Permanent"

I tried a few statements from the Internet but it looks like either my logic in incorrect or the syntax I am using is irrelevant. Please help me with how to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: can you post an example what you want?

Comment: I think this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372872/mysql-trigger-if-condition-exists

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an update join:

```
UPDATE emp_leaves a 
INNER JOIN emp_summary b
    ON a.emp_id = b.emp_id
SET a.leave_limit = a.leave_limit + 1.5
WHERE b.emp_status = 'Permanent'
```

Comment: I had tried different inner joins but was unsuccessful. Now I know how it has to be done. Thank you do much. God bless !

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query below to accomplish this:

```
    update emp_leaves set emp_leaves.leave_limit = emp_leaves.leave_limit + 1.5 from emp_summary where emp_leaves.emp_id = emp_summary.emp_id and emp_summary.emp_status = 'Permanent';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
Use Below format :

UPDATE emp_leaves SET emp_leaves.leave_limit = emp_leaves.leave_limit + 1.5
FROM emp_summary 
WHERE emp_leaves.emp_id = emp_summary.emp_id AND emp_summary.emp_status =  
'Permanent'
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thanks.