# What's the correct syntax to create a trigger with an IF condition that updates a table?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, database-trigger

I keep getting a syntax error with my CREATE TRIGGER MySQL despite following similar syntax in the answers on these threads:

[211853](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211853/update-value-in-table-based-on-condition-in-other-table-with-trigger)

[5372872](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372872/mysql-trigger-if-condition-exists)

But I get:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11

I use XAMPP, and I'm currently trying to run this code in PHPMyAdmin to ensure it works before adding to a PDO query in PHP...

```
                CREATE TRIGGER before_mediaitems_update
                BEFORE UPDATE 
                ON mediaitems
                FOR EACH ROW 
                BEGIN
                    IF (NEW.ConsumptionStatus != OLD.ConsumptionStatus) 
                    THEN
                        update UpdateLog_ConsumptionStatus
                        set MediaItemID = OLD.MediaItemID,
                        UpdateValue = NEW.ConsumptionStatus,
                        DateUpdated = NOW();
                    END IF;
                END
```

Prior to the creation of this trigger, I already run and successfully create the dependent tables, so that part of the script works. In online MySQL syntax checkers, they don't like this syntax but give just as useful error messages as #1064.

Any time a record in the mediaitems table has its ConsumptionStatus changed, I want to record in the UpdateLog_ConsumptionStatus table: the PK of the mediaitem as a FK in UpdateLog_ConsumptionStatus>MediaItemID, then the new ConsumptionStatus value, finally the datetime when the update occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine. The compilation error points at the end of the `update` statement, that is terminated by `;`.

I do suspect that you just need to set a `DELIMITER` other than `;`:

```
DELIMITER //  -- set the delimiter

CREATE TRIGGER before_mediaitems_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON mediaitems
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.ConsumptionStatus != OLD.ConsumptionStatus
    THEN
        update UpdateLog_ConsumptionStatus
        set MediaItemID = OLD.MediaItemID, UpdateValue = NEW.ConsumptionStatus, DateUpdated = NOW();
    END IF;
END
//

DELIMITER ;  -- reset the delimiter
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gq7cBWutxayGVCBzn8jUEF/1)**

Note: presumably, you want an `INSERT` instead of an `UPDATE` - or, at least, the `UPDATE` should have a `WHERE` clause (otherwise it updates all rows in the table).