# Removing "The " with an IF statement in MYSQL Before Insert Trigger

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

Hello helpful world of Stack Overflow!
I am brand new to Triggers, but am having fun using them in my new project.
I have already gotten a few done, but am struggling with setting up a sort field by removing "The " from the beginning of a name.

Being new to this, I am using PHP MyAdmin to build my triggers. So I have it set to my 'aartist' table, Before Insert. The 2 fields are artist_name & artist_sort. This is the full code I've tried with no luck.

```
BEGIN
 IF (left(new.artist_name,4) != "The ")
   THEN
    set new.artist_sort = new.artist_name
   ELSE
    set new.artist_sort = right(new.artist_name,len(new.artist_name)-4)
   END IF;
END
```

I've also tried stripping it back for something more simple, still without luck. The IF statement seems to not work in the TRIGGER.

```
BEGIN
 IF (new.artist_name != new.artist_sort) THEN
    set new.artist_sort = new.artist_name
   END IF;
   
END
```

The Error PHPMyAdmin gives is:

```
 One or more errors have occurred while processing your request:
The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`####`@`localhost` TRIGGER `AddArtist` BEFORE INSERT ON `aartist` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF (new.artist_name != new.artist_sort) THEN set new.artist_sort = new.artist_name END IF; END"
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF; END' at line 4
```

Thank you, as always, for any help in figure out what I might be doing wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some more digging around and found some SQL code that I modified, so instead of using the PHPMyAdmin Trigger Form, I just adjusted the SQL code and it worked! Not 100% sure why it worked with this, but the main change was the Delimiter piece in the code and additional ;s, so my guess is that had something to do with it.

[MySQL trigger if condition exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372872/mysql-trigger-if-condition-exists)

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS AddArtist;

DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER AddArtist BEFORE UPDATE ON `aartist`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF (left(NEW.artist_name,4) = 'The ') THEN
            SET NEW.artist_sort = right(NEW.artist_name, CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.artist_name) - 4);
      ELSE
            SET NEW.artist_sort = NEW.artist_name;
      END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```